# Is there a way of expanding nested key-value pairs of a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries of the following format:

```
list_payloads = [
{
'Id': 320409,
'Name': 'James',
'RelatedPosts':[{'Type':'daily', 'Section':'news'},{'Type':'daily', 'Section':'sports'},{'Type':'weekly', 'Section':'shows'}]
},
{
'Id': 334051,
'Name': 'Scott',
'RelatedPosts':[{'Type':'daily', 'Section':'news'},{'Type':'daily', 'Section':'sports'}]
}
]
```

So first I need it on a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_payloads)
df
```

Output:

[image]

then I need to expand the keys of the 'RelatedPosts' column to new columns of the dataframe. So in this case 'Type', and 'Section' should be the new columns and, for example in the second row 'Scott' would hold only one value (avoid duplicates) for 'Type' where as 'James' would have two values. And same goes with 'Section'.

Desired output:

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this? Take in consideration the real use case the original dataframe could have 50-100k of much larger dictionaries.

I'm pretty new to pandas and only handle basic stuff, I have tried the json_normalize method but can't really understand how it works and the result is never what I need.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack (I don't like `apply(pd.Series)`):

```
import numpy as np

df1 = (df.pop('RelatedPosts').explode().apply(pd.Series)
         .groupby(level=0).agg(np.unique).add_prefix('RelatedPosts_'))
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Id   Name RelatedPosts_Type   RelatedPosts_Section
0  320409  James   [daily, weekly]  [news, shows, sports]
1  334051  Scott           [daily]         [news, sports]
```

Comment: :D always funny when answering a 1h old post almost at the same time as somebody else

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
meta = ['Id', 'Name']

out = (pd.json_normalize(list_payloads, meta=meta,
                         record_path='RelatedPosts')
       .groupby(meta, as_index=False)
       .agg(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))
       )
```

Output:

```
       Id   Name             Type                Section
0  320409  James  [daily, weekly]  [news, sports, shows]
1  334051  Scott          [daily]         [news, sports]
```

If you want a prefix for the non-meta columns:

```
meta = ['Id', 'Name']

out = (pd.json_normalize(list_payloads, meta=meta,
                         record_path='RelatedPosts')
       .groupby(meta)
       .agg(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))
       .add_prefix('RelatedPosts_').reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
       Id   Name RelatedPosts_Type   RelatedPosts_Section
0  320409  James   [daily, weekly]  [news, sports, shows]
1  334051  Scott           [daily]         [news, sports]
```

Comment: This solution looks efficient as well, the only reason I went with Corralien is that already includes the suffix for the newly created columns.

Comment: @MattEzq that's quite easy to add (see update)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite impressed by the pure-pandas answers already here, but I humbly suggest just using a list-comprehension, since you are owrking with `dtype=object` anyway:

```
df = df.assign(
    RelatedPosts_type=[list(dict.fromkeys([d['Type'] for d in ds])) for ds in df['RelatedPosts']],
    RelatedPosts_section=[list(dict.fromkeys([d['Section'] for d in ds])) for ds in df['RelatedPosts']]
)
```